# is there anyway to convert GeometryCollection to a list of geometries?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am a newbie to earth engine. I got a question. how can I have geometrycollection as list of geometries?
I drew some polygons and they are imported as geometrycollection.
I would be grateful if anyone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand your question, geometries method should solve the problem and there is no need of extra stuff.

I mean suppose your geometrycollection is named geom_col. then :

```
 var geom_col_list = geom_col.geometries()
```

would give a list of included geometries.

If i get you wrong, explain in more detail please.